# How to install mod_mono on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, apache-httpd, mono

I'm trying to install mod_mono on Linux Mint Maya/Cinnamon.
I can't seem to find any tutorials or anything on how to do this.

So far, XSP and MonoDevelop seem to be working. I created an MVC solution, started it and it seemed to work fine.

I am also new to apache. This is a learning experience for me. :)

Can someone help me? Is there some "sudo apt-get mod_mono_for_apache" command that I can execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apt-cache` utility has the ability to search for packages. Currently, apache modules are in the form of `libapache2-mod-<module name>`.

On my Debian system:

```
$ apt-cache search libapache2-mod-mono
libapache2-mod-mono - Apache module for running ASP.NET applications on Mono
mono-apache-server1 - ASP.NET 1.1 backend for mod_mono Apache module
mono-apache-server2 - ASP.NET 2.0 backend for mod_mono2 Apache module
```

You can view the full package descriptions using `apt-cache show <package>`.

After a new Apache module is installed in Debian, it still needs to be enabled:

```
a2enmod mono
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

See the [apt-cache manpage](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-cache&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+6.0+squeeze&format=html&locale=en) for more information.

Comment: Thank you - this is information I did not know. I hope that such a package is available on Mint, otherwise I think more legwork on my part will be needed. I will let you know what I find.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed synaptic?

If not....

sudo apt-get install synaptic

once it's installed

sudo synaptic

this will give you a gui interface for apt-get and allow you to search for mod mono and see what it throws up.

Good luck.